# Read id3 tags from mp3 files in a folder through javascript

Tags: javascript, id3

I would like to read id3 tags from mp3 files in a folder with javascript and save it to a textfile. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use Javascript for this?  On the whole, it's probably not the best natural choice.

Comment: I'd say it's probably close to impossible

Comment: If you can find *any* example of reading files from some server-side JavaScript environment, it should be easy to adapt that to reading any files. The mp3 format isn't hard to work with, but honestly though I like JavaScript for all sorts of things, it would not be my first choice here.  If I were doing it for fun I'd use Erlang :-)

Comment: @Sean: Nah, it's totally *possible* (NodeJS has file read stuff, including handling binary files in a reasonable way.) It's just as Andrzej said, it may not be the most natural choice.

Comment: Oh, and if your intention is to read the files on a client machine from JavaScript running on a plain old web page, well, that's going to be somewhere between "really difficult" and "impossible".

Comment: @T.J. server-side is possible, of course, but I assumed the OP meant client-side

Comment: @Sean: I rail against said assumption. :-) He didn't say "browser" or "client" anywhere. JavaScript is not just for browsers. It didn't even start out in browsers, it's been a server-side language since at least 1996 (probably earlier). Obviously I recognize that the vast, vast majority of JavaScript's current use is client-side, though. :-) Call me Quixote.

Comment: @T.J. I have been using JavaScript as a) a scripting language on both mac and windows b) a server side language and c) as a client side language since the 90s, I know what you are talking about. But given the way the question was asked, I just assumed (and still assume) the OP meant client-side

Comment: @Sean: Be kinda nice if the OP bothered to say something either way (both originally and after all this discussion), wouldn't it? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) has a full API for reading/writing files from JavaScript. I'm not aware of any mp3 libraries for it, though...

**Edit**: I assumed you meant JavaScript in a non-browser environment, but everyone else seems to be assuming you mean JavaScript in a web browser. If you do, then you'll struggle until/unless more browsers implement the various File APIs being created by the W3C. [This article](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/) talks about those in some depth. There are very few browsers that have implemented the necessary APIs, though. Chrome may be the only one that lets you traverse directories.

Answer (score 6):

[This man](https://github.com/Tim-Smart/node-id3) did the work of parsing an mp3 file and extracting the tags. It's now up to you to do the loop and to write the result in a text file.

Answer (score 3):

It really annoys me when software developers say something is impossible.  Because, it is rarely so... it is simply beyond their comprehension, creativity, or willingness to work for a solution.

Having said that here (https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader) is someone's work to allow reading of parsed ID3 tags from a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript for Chrome 9 and Webkit browsers, welcome:

http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript

Comment: In case that tumblr link rots (quite likely), this solution only supports ID3v1, and depends on a library called jDataView.

Answer (score 0):

This topic comes first in the search result. None of the answer here mentioned `TagLib`, which is the most famous one that is available as module for nodejs:

https://github.com/nikhilm/node-taglib