# Get id3 tag information from streaming URL using Javascript or Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, id3

I am trying to getting id3 tags for getting an inofrmation about Title,Album art, etc, information from an streaming URL, Lets say for example [this.](http://radiomed.ice.infomaniak.ch/radiomed.mp3)

I would like to do it in js or node js. But I could n't find any proper solution or any way to implement this.

Comment: If you enter `node.js id3` at google, you'll get many possible solutions

Comment: Take a look here - 

1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332384/read-id3-tags-from-mp3-using-javascript

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863608/read-id3-tags-from-mp3-files-in-a-folder-through-javascript